# WPF image binding and INotifyPropertyChanged, issue with image display

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to bind an image in a wpf application. I am using vs2010.

I am pasting code below and explain what I have done, what works and what doesn't.

XAML code:

```
<Image Name="newImage" ImageFailed="newImage_ImageFailed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="auto" Height="auto"  Margin="5" Source="{Binding imgSource}">
```

C# code:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            arraytoImage atim = new arraytoImage();
            newImage.DataContext = atim;
         }
```

Code below is in different namespace, where `arraytoImage` class is implemented. This class takes a cuda array, creates a bitmap and then converts it in into a bitmapimage using memorystream. For now, I am setting a random color to all the pixels, just to see if that binding works. But it doesn't. Below I have pasted a code that displays the image.

I am sure that bitmapimage is correctly created. I think the issue is incorrect binding.

```
class arraytoImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // displays images (focused files)

        private BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        private BitmapImage testim = new BitmapImage();

        public BitmapImage  arraytoImageCon(cuFloatComplex[] dataIn, int wid, int ht)
        {
            //code that generates bitmapimage

        }



  public BitmapImage imgSource
    {
        get { return testim1; }
        set
        {
            if (testim1 != value)
            {
                testim1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("imgSource");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Edit: calling arrayToImageCon:

```
public class ReadRawFiles
{  
     //Tons of code
     public void focusdata()
     {
        //tons of code
        arraytoImage atoi = new arraytoImage();
        BitmapImage tmp=  atoi.arraytoImageCon(datafft_azi, nazimuth,nrange);
        atoi.imgSource=tmp;
     }
}
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong.

Thanks a lot in advance. Kindly ask further details if I missed something.

Regards

Comment: Your code is a bit messy. Why don't you get rid of the testim1 and return bitmapImage directly. Also where do you call arrayToImage con? Why don't you call the setter there directly, so the property gets properly raised?

Comment: Try `test = bitmapImage;` instead of `testim1 = bitmapImage;`

Comment: @dowhilefor its messy, because I am in initial phase of learning. Please be a bit elaborative. Thanks

Comment: You won't try it or it didn't work?^^

Comment: lol. I tried. I gave error. Error: {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

Comment: @dowhilefor I returned bitmapimage directly. Still it doesnt work. How do I call the setter directly where I call arraytoimagecon?? (newImage.Source=bitmapiamge?)

Comment: First of, what i mean by messy is, we need more time to figure out your code instead be focused on the problem. Now the steps are easy: Load the image, set the property and raise the property, can you clarify that this is the case? The property set could be done in your arrayToImageCon method, and the raise is done in the setter of course. So from outside just calling arrayToImagecon should be enough. check your output for errors, use snoop to check if the datacontext is correct.

Comment: Question updates; 
In method arraytoimagecon, image created, set the property. Datacontext is set to property test, which will raise it. I am all confused where am I wrong.

Comment: You need to add `testim1 = value;` in the setter and also add  `private BitmapImage testim1;` Cause in the getter you return testim1, but testim1 never gets a value.

Comment: i tried that too. still no luck. does namespace make difference here?

Comment: make a debug point at the getter and check if the value is not null. I don't see where u set the value for `testim1` in your first code...

Comment: its not null, i updated the question.

Comment: if i set imgSource in MainWindow(); it displays the image. if i set in ReadRawFile, it doesnt.

Comment: edited. anyone with insight please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

binding is set to one instance. I was making multiple instances.